# Lost in the Math of a method

Tags: java, math, methods

The method should increase the balance by the given amount. However, the maximum balance on a card is 150. In case the balance after loading money would be more than that, it should be truncated to 150.

Method

```
public void loadMoney(int amount) {
    if(balance + amount > 150){
        balance = balance +(balance + amount - 150);}
    else{balance += amount;

    }
```

Main

```
    ACard card = new ACard(10);
    System.out.println(card);

    card.loadMoney(15);
    System.out.println(card);

    card.loadMoney(10);
    System.out.println(card);

    card.loadMoney(200);
    System.out.println(card);
```

Outputs

```
ACard{balance=10}
ACard{balance=25}
ACard{balance=35}
ACard{balance=120} //this blance should be 150
```

Comment: just do `balance = 150` instead of that expression.

Comment: Just set balance to 150, if balance + amount > 150.

Comment: Actually now your formula is:
newBalance = oldBalance*2 + loadAmount - 150, so answer 120 here is totally correct :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to limit a number from exceeding a high boundary, then you can use `Math.min`

```
public void loadMoney(int amount) {
     balance = Math.min(150, balance + amount);
}
```

Want to prevent negative balances?

```
Math.max(0, Math.min(150, balance + amount));
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to to store the amount of money that exceeded the limit? for future usage

Comment: That wasn't your initial question, so I'll leave that as a learning excersise. The other answers are better suited for that, anyways

Comment: well, this was a math question as you can read it on the title and the tags, you solved with a class method. not what I was looking for, or asking

Comment: I did read the question, and all you asked for was limiting the balance if it exceeded 150.

Comment: Estos gringos piensan que todos deben hablar fluidamente su idioma, si tengo problemas para expresar correctamente la pregunta es por que no es mi idioma nativo, buena suerte con su próximo presidente.

Comment: Okay...  Puedo leer Español.... And that's a StackOverflow thing, not my personal opinion. You expressed yourself perfectly in the comments, so you should have said that in the initial question.

Comment: And Australia/England don't have a president

Comment: Спасибо за удовольствие , вверх Trump!

Comment: Please stop being ignorant of other English speaking countries

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_entities_where_English_is_an_official_language .....yes, sure, the world has only 3 english speaking countries, you dumb texan......you amuse me

Comment: I live in Texas, doesn't make me Texan.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (balance + amount > 150) {
    programmer.balance += balance + amount - 150:
    balance = 150;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing things more complicated than necessary.

```
public void loadMoney(int amount)
{
  balance += amount;
  if (balance > 150)
    balance = 150;
}
```